# Pandas Groupby get max of multiple columns but in order

Tags: python, pandas

I have below pandas dataframe

```
COlA    ColB    Result  Freq
A       B       1       3000
A       C       0.2     4000
A       D       1       5000
A       E       0.3     9000
A       F       0.4     8000
B       A       0.4     1000
B       C       0.1     4000
B       D       0.1     5000
B       E       0.2     9000
B       F       0.3     8000
...
```

I want to `groupby` `ColA`  and get max of `Result` and `Types`in order i.e.  in such a way that it should first find the max of `Result` column if there are more than one max row then look at `Freq` and find the max there. I've tried using `groupby().max().reset_index()` but not getting the desired output

Expected Output

```
COlA    ColB    Result  Freq
A       D       1       5000
B       A       0.4     1000
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort by Results/Freq and then `groupby`+`first`:

```
(df.sort_values(by=['Result', 'Freq'], ascending=False)
   .groupby(['COlA'], as_index=False).first()
)
```

output:

```
  COlA ColB  Result  Freq
0    A    D     1.0  5000
1    B    A     0.4  1000
```

*NB. warning your column name is `COlA` (with a capital O)*

Comment: Legend. Hi @mozway  ```COlA``` is  (with a capital O) in my sample dataset, so all good. and thank you so much . I have seen your answers in multiple pandas posts, keep doing the good work. Accepted + Upvoted

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    return dd.sort_values(by=['Result','Freq'],ascending=[False,False]).head(1)

df1.groupby('COlA').apply(function1).reset_index(drop=True)


out

  COlA ColB  Result  Freq
0    A    D     1.0  5000
1    B    A     0.4  1000
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?